# No map is displaying in Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have trying to get Google map to run on a Androidapplication. But it doesn't work.

I copy/pasted a lot of tutorials but they have not worked for me. The map applicetion is opening up and the zoom-in/zoom-out symbols is displayed but the map is not visible. I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is a example of a project I have tried.

GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "festivalapp.com.mapapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

Here is the activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    if (map!=null){
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                );
    }

} }
```

MANIFEST

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="festivalapp.com.mapapp">
    <permission
    android:name="festivalapp.com.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="festivalapp.com.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="A*******************************8" />


</application>
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me

Comment: Are you sure your Maps API_KEY is correct? The problem you described usually happens when your API_KEY isn't right. Also, look in your log, there must be some indication why it's happening

Comment: Yes, I looked at Google and the key-value is right.

Comment: I just noticed that I got the packagename in google account wrong. Gonna se if that helps

Comment: Thanks sharj! After days of trying to find out what is wrong it was the packagename for the api-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you described usually happens when your API_KEY isn't right. Also, look in your log, there must be some indication why it's happening.